# Regular expression too large problem

Tags: string-manipulation, system-limitations

```
pattern = Names["*"];

StringMatchQ["Bold", pattern[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]]

(*
    True
*)

StringMatchQ["Bold", pattern]
```

#### Error Information:

---

RegularExpression::msg20: Regular expression too large in StartOfString~~<<5433>>}~~EndOfString. >>

question is how to overcome this problem, or is there some option to adjust this.

following is some extends for pattern, this is something different from the case in Martin's answer.

```
pattern=#~~__&/@Names["*"];
```

Context is in dealing with the String generated by Input Cells, then one is in front of the large number of Names and Pattern with Names. Since my question about context is not so clear, I can't add too much detail.

Comment: Is the self-edit intended as a solution, clarification, or something else?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard hi, something clarification, why I donot do like the solution in Martin's answer

Comment: Is the use of `Names` merely a terse way to generate a long list of strings or does it have some bearing on your real application?  If you are looking for a *solution* rather than merely an understanding of the origin of the problem I suggest you provide some context.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes, actually , both as your thoughts. Context is in dealing with the String generated by Input Cells, then one is in front of the large Names and Patterns with Names. Since my question about context is not so clear, I can't add too much detail.

Comment: I just have checked your code with version 10.4 and found that there is no error anymore: the output of `StringMatchQ["Bold", pattern]` is `True` without any messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Source

*Mathematica* [makes use of](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html) the [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) library.  According to http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt :

> Within  a  compiled  pattern,  offset values are used to point from
>   one    part to another (for example, from an opening parenthesis to an
>   alter-    nation  metacharacter).  By default, in the 8-bit and 16-bit
>   libraries,    two-byte values are used for these offsets, leading to a
>   maximum  size    for  a compiled pattern of around 64K. This is
>   sufficient to handle all    but the most gigantic patterns. 
>   Nevertheless, some people do  want  to    process  truly  enormous
>   patterns, so it is possible to compile PCRE to    use three-byte or
>   four-byte offsets by adding a setting such as
>
> ```
>  --with-link-size=3
> ```
>
> to the configure command. The value given must be 2, 3, or 4.  For 
>   the    16-bit  library,  a  value of 3 is rounded up to 4. In these
>   libraries,    using longer offsets slows down the operation of PCRE
>   because it has to    load  additional  data  when  handling them. For
>   the 32-bit library the    value is always 4 and cannot be overridden;
>   the value  of  --with-link-    size is ignored.

Apparently you have run into this limitation:

```
StringPattern`PatternConvert[Names["*"]][[1]] // StringLength
```

> ```
> 81958
> ```

I don't believe you can change this for *Mathematica*.

### Solutions

As Martin points out you do not even need string patterns for verbatim matches, but in other cases I suggest you split the pattern into smaller parts and run multiple passes.

[`StringCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringCases.html) apparently does not convert its second parameter to a single regular expression:

```
pattern = # ~~ __ & /@ Names["*"];

StringCases["Bold 123", pattern]
```

> ```
> {"Bold 123"}
> ```

One could therefore use something like:

```
pattern = StartOfString ~~ # ~~ __ & /@ Names["*"];

StringCases["Bold 123", pattern] =!= {}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to check if `Bold` exists in `Names`, there's no need for string matching:

```
MemberQ[Names["*"], "Bold"]
(* True *)
```

or even

```
Names["Bold"] != {}
(* True *)
```

`Names` also takes more elaborate string patterns, just as `StringMatchQ` does.

That being said, even in your example, I don't understand, why you're matching all the names against `Bold` instead of the other way round:

```
Or @@ StringMatchQ[Names["*"], "Bold"]
(* True *)
```

Comment: hi, how about `pattern=#~~__&/@Names["*"];`

Comment: @HyperGroups If you really want to form one huge pattern from the the names, see Mr. Wizard's answer. But I don't see why you'd want to do that.